# MYSQL: Прошу помощи в оптимизации запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация

Привет, прошу помощи в оптимизации запроса, индекса или таблицы в целом... Есть запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.`id`, i.`name`
FROM `p_items` as i, `p_cats_sync` as c 
WHERE c.`id` = i.`id` 
  AND c.`cat_id` IN (109,152,153,156,157,158,161,163,166,140,266) 
  AND c.`status` = 1 
  AND c.`p_status` = 1 
ORDER BY i.`status` DESC, i.`views` DESC 
LIMIT 40, 10;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  c   range   PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY     4   NULL    412     Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...
1   SIMPLE  i   ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   c.id    1
```

Таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_items` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `views` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`status`,`views`),
  UNIQUE KEY `status` (`status`,`views`,`id`),
  KEY `views` (`views`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2594 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_cats_sync` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cat_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `p_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`,`status`,`p_status`,`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Запрос выполняется очень долго (~0.4-0.5s), даже на не очень большой БД (порядка 1400 записей) Пробовал просто запрос

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT c.`id`
FROM `p_cats_sync` AS c
WHERE c.`cat_id` IN ( 109, 152, 153, 156, 157, 158, 161, 163, 166, 140, 266 )
  AND c.`status` =1
  AND c.`p_status` =1
```

Выполняется быстро, хоть и с временной таблицей, убрать ее не получается :(

```
1   SIMPLE  c   range   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   NULL    412     Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

Прошу помощи в оптимизации, т.к. количество записей растет очень быстро

Comment: Ну раз `DISTINCT + ORDER BY` - никуда от temporary не деться. Рассмотрите изменения PK на `p_cats_sync` на ``(`status`,`p_status`,`cat_id`,`id`)``.

Comment: А почему именно эта последовательность? Попробовал, SIMPLE c range PRIMARY,id PRIMARY 4 NULL 458 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f, все тоже

Comment: *А почему именно эта последовательность?* Я ориентируюсь на последовательность условий во WHERE. Жаль, у тебя нет сведений по вариативности значений полей...

Comment: Можно подробней, про вариативность значений?

Comment: Ну это, грубо говоря, количество значений в поле. Или, в данном случае, какой процент записей таблицы отбирается двумя условиями ``c.`status` = 1 AND c.`p_status` = 1``.

Comment: c.`status` = 1 AND c.`p_status` = 1 отбирается %90, скажем статусы 0 бывают редко

Comment: Тогда эти поля в индексе вообще не имеют смысла для данного запроса. А если ещё и по `cat_id` отбирается больше 5% - то индекс по `id` оптимален.

Comment: по cat_id выборка порядка 1%. Сейчас попробовал PRIMARYcat_id+id, результат не меняется, ни по explain, ни по времени запроса

Comment: Попробуйте `PRIMARY (cat_id,id)` и временно удалить индекс по `id`. Или даже FORCE INDEX... Изменится ли время выполнения запроса?

Comment: Выполнил через FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY), время тоже, explain хуже (больше строк стало) 1  SIMPLE  c  range  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  2  NULL 558  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE  i  ref  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  3  c.id  1

Comment: @MiniD, меня смущает дико Ваше `key_len: 412`, вам реально нужно перебирать DISTINCT-ом не только `id`, но еще и `name`? а судя по этой цифре - они там офигенно длинные у Вас. Внезапно, но попробуйте убрать DISCTINCT и вместо него сделать GROUP BY i.id

Comment: @Александр Белинский, 412 это не key_len, это rows, key_len - 4, попробовал через group by, результат тот же, и по времени тоже, `1  SIMPLE  c  range  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  4  NULL 452  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...`